# is there a way to access python 2.7 jupyter notebook on my linux desktop from my Ipad?

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I have ubuntu 14.04 with anaconda python 2.7, tensorflow, and jupyter notebook.
Since jupyter notebook runs on chrome, i was wondering whether i can access my linux through my chrome on my ipad.
it seems to work if my ipad and linux are on same internal wifi. but is there a way to access from an external connection?

ps. it seems jupyter hub only seems to work for python3

Comment: If you already have it working on internal wifi, it's more a question for //networkengineering.stackexchange.com or //superuser.com .

Comment: oh really? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using remote desktop on chrome like [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en)

Hope it helps :)